# How to pass an image in HTTP POST request and insert into a Database Table

Tags: php, html, post, attachment

I need to retrieve form values to `insert.php` file in order to store them in the database. However one of the elements in the form is a file chooser dialog to upload an image file in JPG or other file format.

I found this code online to send the image via a post request, but cannot get it to work correctly

```
$pic=($_FILES['photo'][image']);
```

It only displays the name of the file and not the actual file itself

Comment: Please consult the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to add the `enctype` attribute to your HTML form. Like this:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Next, when this will be sent on the next page use the `$_FILES` global array instead of the `$_POST` array to retrieve the image.

```
<?php
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "/var/www/image.jpg" );
    echo("<img src='image.jpg'");
?>
```

All text data will be sent using `$_POST` but the file will be transferred using `$_FILES`.

**Edit:** If you further want to insert this uploaded data in the table (although this is never recommended and is a huge performance loss)

```
$image = file_get_contents( "/var/www/image.jpg" );
$image = addslashes( $image );
...
$sql = "INSERT INTO pictures(image) VALUES('" . $image . "')";
//remaining MySQL and PHP code
```

**Note:** Here I am considering `/var/www` as my web folder which is configured as default **localhost** on Linux machines.

Comment: yes I have added that in the form, but I need to know how to show the image and not the file name

Comment: Supposing you have named your control as **photo** `<input type="file" name="photo" />` you will be able to access it in your PHP code as `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']` where **tmp_name** is the temporary name given to the uploaded file. Last thing required is to move it to your desired location: `move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "/uploads/new.jpg" );`

Comment: thanks but after passing the image file in the parameter I get an Unedfioned index error 

$picImg=($_FILES['photo']['181352_4195558337034_1286935116_n.jpg']);

Comment: well the code you gave was working, however what I require is to save the image into the database and not into any folder. So when I try to pass the variable from $_FILES to the SQL query I receive the undefined index error

Comment: Normally images and files are always saved in a directory and their name and link is only saved in the database. Otherwise your database column must be of BLOB type.

Comment: yes it is BLOB data type
so basically, do I have to save this in a directory and then save in the database and again delete the directory image. Or is there a direct way to do so

Comment: I have edited the answer please check and approve if its good enough.

Comment: Thanks, it should work now except for the Notice: Undefined index: photo error msg. My form is using GET that is not a problem right

Comment: Well I posted the solution using **POST** anyway modify whichever way you like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14268/discussion-between-yoosuf-and-muhammad-ahmad-zafar)